# Exibir linha por linha do arquivo.txt ao clicar

Tags: php

Sou iniciante em PHP, estou tentando criar um botão, sendo que de acordo com que eu fosse clicando a próxima linha do arquivo seria exibida.

1º click - linha 1 é exibida /
2º click - linha 2 é exibida / e assim por diante

```html
<?php
$linhas = file("texto.txt");
for($i = 0;$i < count($linhas);$i++) {
echo "<button value='". $linhas[$i]. "'>". $linhas[$i] ."</button>";
}
?>
```

Mas no código acima, todas as linhas acabam virando botôes:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu gostaria que acontecesse:
Se o código estiver lendo a linha 5, ele exibirá somente a linha 5.
Se o código estiver lendo a linha 6, ele exibirá somente a linha 6.

Exemplo mais claro do que estou tentando fazer:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score -2):

Isso não é um problema de PHP, é de HTML e JavaScript

Você precisa alterar o estilo do display da sua linha para esconder ou mostrar o conteúdo.

```js
function toggleDisplay(e) {
  let linhas = document.getElementsByClassName('linha');
  for (let i = 0; i < linhas.length; i++) {
    linhas[i].style.display = i === e ? '' : 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleDisplay(0)">Clique Aqui1</button>
<button onclick="toggleDisplay(1)">Clique Aqui2</button>
<button onclick="toggleDisplay(2)">Clique Aqui3</button>
<p class="linha" style="display: none">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p class="linha" style="display: none">Nam vulputate, risus non finibus commodo, dolor est euismod mauris, eu condimentum enim lectus id risus.</p>
<p class="linha" style="display: none">Fusce sed sapien tristique, pellentesque libero vitae, elementum erat.</p>
```

Há varias formas de fazer isso, frameworks geralmente tornam isso mais prático, mas considerando que você ainda nem sabia por onde começar, sugiro você ler sobre HTML antes de prosseguir com sua ideia.